# unescaped character literals detection error

Tags: init-file, error-handling, characters

When I reload my init file I get an error (or warning) saying

```
unescaped character literals `?(', `?)', `?[', `?]' detected!
```

What does this error (warning) mean and how can one fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section [2.3.3.1 Basic Char Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html#Basic-Char-Syntax) of the Elisp manual says:

```
The usual read syntax for alphanumeric characters is a question mark
followed by the character; thus, ‘?A’ for the character ‘A’, ‘?B’ for
the character ‘B’, and ‘?a’ for the character ‘a’.

   For example:

     ?Q ⇒ 81     ?q ⇒ 113

   You can use the same syntax for punctuation characters.  However, if
the punctuation character has a special syntactic meaning in Lisp, you
must quote it with a ‘\’.  For example, ‘?\(’ is the way to write the
open-paren character.  Likewise, if the character is ‘\’, you must use a
second ‘\’ to quote it: ‘?\\’.
```

Your init file contains `?(` but Emacs prefers to see `?\(`. The same goes for the other three characters mentioned in the warning.

You can load the Elisp manual inside Emacs with `C-h i`.